# How to add #navbar to all page links?

Tags: menus, filters, widgets, child-theme, theme-twenty-thirteen

I have several Wordpress websites with large images at their tops, using 2013 child theme.

How to add `#navbar` anchor to all page links, so that the browser scrolls down a bit, when a user clicks a link in the *Pages* widget?

[image: screenshot]

(because otherwise users think that nothing has happened after they click, since they see the same big image again).

In the file [wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php) I have found the source code for the `WP_Widget_Pages`, but I am not sure how to modify it the best way (it should probably happen in my `twentythirteen-child` theme too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add a filter to `page_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_link/) to modify link output:

```
function wpd_add_fragment_to_pages( $url ) {
    return $url . '#navbar';
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpd_add_fragment_to_pages' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added your code to `/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/functions.php` and it works

Comment: just note that it will apply to all page links output, you could target just the sidebar by adding it just before sidebar output and removing it immediately after.

Comment: ps: and just in case a fragment is already added from another plugin/theme, we could filter late and check for any existing #. I wish PHP/WP would ship with a complete url builder ;-)

Comment: I've changed the return statement to check if there is an anchor already: `return ( preg_match( '/#\w*$/', $url ) ? $url : $url . '#navbar' );`